# The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folders but I can't edit it

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-transfer

I want to move a file but its filepath/filename is too long.

Its context menu only shows a reduced list of options and rename isn't in the list,
pressing F2 after selecting the file in the file explorer doesn't yield any result and trying the RENAME command from command prompt just yields a "Filename or extension is too long" error.

How can I rename this file so that it becomes editable?

(The filepath to this file includes some chinese characters but the command prompt chcp is already set on 950 which is the proper value for them)

Comment: you can always try booting off a linux live CD, and see if you can edit the filename there.

Comment: @Frank-Thomas I booted in a Debian/Linux system and I could open and edit the files without any problem. They were plain-text files so I renamed them adding the .txt extension and now they are useable from Windows too. I lost the line breaks but that's fine.

Comment: My fault, this was an audio file not a text file. Anyways it's editable and accessible after using a different OS to rename it.

Comment: @maja If you have solved the problem then you can answer and accept your own question. It would be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted in a Debian/Linux system and I could open and edit the files without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt as from that path and Use this command-
(if there is one file in that folder)

`ren *.* filename.extension`

or open command prompt as administrator from any other path(like from system32) use this

```
ren "filepath with extension" filename.extension
```

Comment: @SSAURAABHH I tried ren [filepath]/*.* file.wav but I obtain "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Open command prompt from that folder in which the file is!if your file is situated at folder1,then press shift+right click,you get a option open command line from here then use this command line!

Comment: Even like this all I can obtain is "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: or i'm telling you a simple method,maybe it work!
open property of that file and rename from there(in general tab,the first line),ensure that file is not in use!

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified." if u get this means u r not doing in a right way!

Comment: don't use [filepath]!
use as i described!

Comment: @SSAURABAHH I tried the methods you suggested but they didn't work.I would be curious to know the reason but in the end I did edit the files from a different OS.

Comment: @SSAURABAHH btw, propoerties wasn't available from the context menu as rename wasn't

Comment: then attach some screenshots to let me and other know what problem exactly it is?
if not want to do so try my last recommendation,download unlocker 1.9.2,right click on that file and click unlocker then select rename then press unlock all!may be it work!

Comment: @SSAURABAHH I would add some screenshots, but I'm not reputable enough. Anyways I did solve the problem editing the file from another OS. Now, it's accessible and editable from Windows too. (It has been a long time since I used Unlocker, I'm not sure it would have helped in this case, the problem here was that the renaming tools of the system were not accessible)

Comment: Glad to know u have solved the problem,
try tweaking.com's all in one windows repair software to repair that system problem(it helps me many times ) :)
i'll delete this answer after your next comment! :)

Comment: All right, I posted the Linux answer, still I'd keep the hint about tweaking.com because not everyone has a Linux partition sitting around whenever need arise ;)

Comment: of course :-D  Tweaking.com all in repair is very good tool! :-)